# Core Data tutorial out-of-date?

Tags: xcode, macos, core-data

I started going through the "Core Data Tutorial for iOS" at developer.apple.com but am stuck just a few paragraphs in.  It says to create a new project using the "Window-Based Application template" which doesn't seem to exist in my version of xcode (4.5.1) so I used "Single View Application" instead.  The problem then is there's no xcdatamodeld file that should have been provided by the template, and the app delegate properties (like NSManagedObjectContext) that it discusses are also missing.

Is there an updated tutorial for 4.5.1 from Apple that covers this material?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: They did change things a little in their templates, as they do fairly frequently, but you should be able to start from the Master-Detail Application, Utility Application, or Empty Application and check the Use Core Data option. The Empty Application will probably get you closest to their tutorial, then you'll just have to add back in the elements that are missing.

Comment: Thanks!  That looks like it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, that tutorial needs to be updated for Xcode 4 and iOS 6.

Here is the code of the tutorial updated for Xcode 4, with some instructions:
https://github.com/arielelkin/Locations